# If an open set $U$ contains a compact set $K$, then exists minimum distance a point $x$ can be to $K$ that $x \not\in U$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $K$ compact and $U$ is open, both in $\mathbb{R}$, such that $K \subseteq U$. Is it true that exists a $x \in U\backslash K$ such that if for some $k \in K$, $|y - k| < d(x, K)$, then $y\in U$?

By $d(x, K)$ I mean $\inf\{|x-k|: k \in K\}$.

I've tried proving by contradction but didn't got any far. Any hints or ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the previous comment, I misunderstood the question.

Let $d=d(K,\mathbb{R} \setminus U)=\inf \{|k-v|: k\in K,\ v\notin U\}>0$ and let $x\in U \setminus K$ be such that
$d(x,K) < d$. Then, if $y$ and $k$ are as in your statement we have that
$$d(y,K) \leq d(y,k) < d = d(\mathbb{R} \setminus U, K),$$
so that $y \in U.$

Comment: Nice, but why there is such $x$?

Comment: Let $k\in K$ and $v \in \mathbb{R} \setminus U$ be such that $|k-v|=d$. Notice that these two must be boundary points. Then, any point other than $k$ and $v$ in the line segment between $k$ and $v$ (you can write  this as $\{tk+(1-t)v:\ t\in [0,1] \}$) is such a point.

Comment: And the existence of such pair $(k, v)$ is because $K$ is compact and $d(\cdot, \mathbb{R}\backslash U)$ is continuous?

Comment: Exactly. This is how you prove that the distance between a compact and a closed set (which are disjoint) is positive.